# Self-service hotels/hotel chains around the world?

Tags: budget, hotels

In Finland there is a hotel chain (Omena Hotels), where you book your room online and on a day of arrival the system sends you SMS & email with the numpad code to enter the lobby and your room. No reception desk *at all* (and I found that concept quite smart because lower salary expenses seem to mean lower room prices)

Is there any other hotel chains or individual hotels that operate with the same exact concept?

Comment: No direct experience, but I think many Japanese Love Hotels operate without contact with any staff, but it might be a bit different process.

Comment: Hilton seems to be implementing "digital keys" at many properties, where the door lock is Bluetooth enabled and you open it with an app on your phone.   The reception desk still exists but you don't have to visit it. Does that fit your criteria?

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly like you've described, but close...

[citizenM](https://www.citizenm.com/) hotels use an automated check-in system.  Upon arrival at the hotel you enter your details, swipe your credit card, and the system issues you with a keycard that gives you access to your room.   You then use the same kiosks to checkout at the completion of your stay.  At no point do you deal with a human.

Many hotel chains, including Hilton and Marriott hotels, also offer some form of e-checkin and digital key combination, normally using an app on your phone.  This allows you to check-in from your phone, use your phone to open the room to your door, and then check-out using your their app - so again, no human interaction.

However in at least some cases these e-check-in/digital key systems will require you to visit the front desk, in particular to show ID (especially where required by law) and/or your credit card (especially if it's a card you haven't used at that chain before).

Comment: Those citizenM hotels seem to be pretty close to Omena Hotels concept! Do you know, are those hotels also on average cheaper than "usual" hotels in their cities?

Answer (score 1):

Many budgets hotels use **safes/keyboxes**, I've been to maybe 10 of them.

I've also been to one that used **code locks** instead.

Personally **I prefer the code locks** as I don't have to keep track of a key and I've nothing to do when checking out except for leaving the room.

One way of knowing if the hotels are using systems like this is to check the reception hours which aren't long, like 12:00-15:00 with check-in 24 hours means there's probably a system like this in-place.

Comment: that does not answer the op's question.

Comment: Can you please edit your 'answer' so that it does include specific hotels or chains? Names are allowed in cases like this.